React dnd-kit z-index
I created a drag-and-drop application using React and dnd-kit. I have a main grid (calendar) which contains many cells which are all droppable components.
I also have some other containers (also droppable) from which draggable elements can be dragged unto the grid. This all works fine, the dragged items are "above" all other elements in the DOM.
The problem occurs when I want to drag a draggable element back from the calendar grid to one of the default drop zones. As long as the dragged element is within the calendar container, it is visible, but as soon as it leaves it, it is "behind" other DOM elements.
Some more information

Draggable element when static: {position: relative | absolute (depending on if it's in the calendar or not)}
Draggable element style when dragged: {z-index: 1, position: absolute}
Calendar grid style: {display: grid; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
Default container style: {position: relative, overflow: hidden auto}

The overall DOM structure is quite complicated and nested with hundreds of draggable and droppable elements. I just simply want the dragged element to be above everything on the page. Any ideas and/or suggestions?
I experimented a lot with different stacking contexts and configurations,
with css isolation: isolate,
also adding the element to the body (document.body.appendChild(myDraggableElement)), but with no success.
I tried creating a DndContext modifier
const bringToFront = ({ transform }) => { return { ...transform, transform:translate(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px) scale(${transform.scaleX}, ${transform.scaleY}) translateZ(1px) }; };
Tried
transform-style: preserve-3d; transform:translateZ(1px);
mentioned here: Override CSS Z-Index Stacking Context

I kind of found a workaround by using a react Portal -> https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal
If the draggable component is being dragged, I add the append the component to the document.body and position it using the x and y coordinates of the mouse. As soon as the dragging is complete, the component is rendered normally.
function DraggableOverlay({children, x, y}) {
    return createPortal(
    <div style={{ position: 'fixed', top: y, left: x, zIndex: 9999, pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
        {children}
    </div>,
    document.body
    );
}

This is how I then use render the draggable component:
return (
    <>
    {isDragging ? 
        <DraggableOverlay x={mousePosition.x} y={mousePosition.y}> 
            {draggableElement}
        </DraggableOverlay> 
        : draggableElement}
    </>
)

This works by overwriting (or more precisely creating a new) CSS stacking order.
